# I want the user to not be able to advance to the next screen if he/she doesn't enter the required information

Tags: javascript, html

The function receives the username and password of the user. If either are left empty, nothing happens and they won't be linked to google.ca if they click the "Go" button. If they filed in the required sections then they will be directed to google.ca. For some reason, if any of the text boxes are left unfilled and the Go button is pressed, it brings me to a 404 error page when I want it to just stay on that page until the user fills the textbox. What is causing this problem? This is the HTML file.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" id="form" onsubmit="return go(document.getElementById('username'), document.getElementById('password'))">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="16" id="username" onKeyUp="updateLength('username', 'usernameLength')" onblur="checkTextField(this);"/> <span id="usernameLength"></span></td></tr>     
        <tr><td>Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" id="password" onKeyUp="updateLength('password', 'passwordLength')"> <span id="passwordLength" onblur="checkTextField(this);"></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Go" id="goButton" onclick="go(username, password)"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here is the js file

```
function loginFunction() {
    var url = "login.html";
    window.open(url);
}

function createAccountFunction() {
    var url2 = "createAccount.html";
    window.open(url2);
}

function go(username, password) {
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        var url = "https://www.google.ca/";
        window.open(url);
    }
}

function updateLength(field, output) {
    var curr_length = document.getElementById(field).value.length;
    var field_mLen = document.getElementById(field).maxLength;
    document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = curr_length + '/' +     field_mLen;
}

function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '')
        alert("Field is empty");
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('username')` gets you the element, which is always not null (given your code).  You need to check the *value* of that element in either your `go()` or the `onsubmit` call to `go`

Comment: Why not use the HTML 5 attribute of required on your inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't stopping the default event of the `onsubmit`. You can do that by changing your `go` function to:

```
function go(username, password) {
    return function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            var url = "https://www.google.ca/";
            window.open(url);
        }
    }
}
```

You also don't need the `return` in the HTML. Just call the function.

Comment: Returning a function from go()? That's not going to work. (In any case there are other issues with the go() function.)

Comment: @nnnnnn OP is using `go()` as an event handler, but isn't handling the event. My modification adds the closure so that OP can handle the event and stop the page from reloading.

Comment: @Michael are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I'm not using an IDE I'm just using notepad++

Comment: @Michael I meant in your browser's console. If you are using Chrome, right click the page, select "Inspect", go to the "Console" tab, reload your page, try the button, and see what happens. (IE, Firefox, and Safari also have consoles). As a JS developer, the console will be by far your best friend.

Comment: When the submit event occurs the inline onsubmit handler calls go(). Your modification returns another function that will never be called - all the browser cares about is whether or not go() returned false.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code logic, but maybe I can offer you a way to fix your code by yourself.

You have a form and a button. If you click on the button you execute the go() function. Because the button is a submit button, on the same click you execute one more time the go() function.

My advice is to create a new function, you may name it **validate()**:

```
function validate() {
    var username = document.get........ 
    var password = document.get........ 
    // more logic here, if need
    if(!username || !password) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true
}
```

and now, your submit button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" id="goButton" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

The form won't submit if the **validate()** function returns **false**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so when would I use the go function?

Comment: you use the go function onsubmit. But, if validate() returns false, the onsubmit won't run.

Comment: The inline handler would need to say "return validate()", otherwise the return value from the function will be ignored.

Comment: Of course "return validate()". Thanks for remark. Code updated.